# Passing button tag to perform segue identifier

Tags: ios

I have a table view with custom cells. On the cell there are buttons identified with tags.
Every button performs an action. As example:

```
-(void)mapa_button_action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CANCELAR BUTTON CLICKED=%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    NSString *employee =[[historialServicios objectAtIndex:sender.tag] valueForKey:@"driverId"];
    NSLog(@"EMPLOYEE=%@",employee);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapa_conductor_segue" sender:self];

}
```

As you can see, the button is identified with the sender.tag property.
In this case, the action performs a segue, and later, it performs the prepareForSegue method, where I can pass variables to the new view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapa_conductor_segue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"INDEXPATH=%@",indexPath);
    }
}
```

What I need is to retrieve the values from the selected cell to the new view controller.
I am able to get the values in the map_button_action method, but I don't know how  to pass these values to the new controller.

I must use the performSegueWithIdentifier action in order to maintain the view controllers structure, I am using SWRevealViewControllers.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a useless argument as the sender when you call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender. If you want the button's tag to be available in prepareForSegue, then set that tag (converted to an NSNumber) as the sender -- you can pass any object you want in that parameter, and it will be the sender in prepareForSegue.

```
-(void)mapa_button_action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CANCELAR BUTTON CLICKED=%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    NSString *employee =[[historialServicios objectAtIndex:sender.tag] valueForKey:@"driverId"];
    NSLog(@"EMPLOYEE=%@",employee);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapa_conductor_segue" sender:@(sender.tag)];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSNumber *)sender {
    NSInteger tag = sender.integerValue;
    // do whatever you need to with the tag
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapa_conductor_segue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"INDEXPATH=%@",indexPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but implementing your proposal, I don't need the if lines. I only need to declare the end view controller and pass the values there, am I right?

Comment: @mvasco, I was only copying your code, so I assumed that's what you wanted. You don't need the if clause if you only have one segue, but you would if there are multiple segues..

Comment: @rdelmar I am just curious, how did you fetch the `indexPathForSelectedRow`

Comment: I am sure your code will work, but for now, it throws an exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HistorialReservasViewController integerValue]:

Comment: @VinayJain, I didn't, that part of the code was the OP's; I didn't change it. However, the cell will not be selected when you touch a button, so indexPathForSelectedRow will be nil.

Comment: @mvasco, Did you change the sender in performSegue to @(sender.tag)?

Comment: @rdelmar yes that was what I was thinking, that if the `indexPath` will be nil how will OP fetch values from the cell.

Comment: You are right, @redelmar, I forgot to change the sender in performSegue...now it works fine. Thank you again.

Comment: @VinayJain, I am fetching the values from the NSMutableArray that is populating the table view, and as index path  I am using the sender.tag from the button action.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapa_conductor_segue"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@"INDEXPATH=%@",indexPath);
    DestinationViewController *objeDest=segue.destinationViewController;
    objeDest.destinationIndexPath=indexPath

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the log of INDEXPATH=(null). As it is in my example.

Answer (score 1):

In the destination `ViewController` create a property(of the type you need to pass data in). You can create an object of the destination controller in your current `ViewController` and set the value of this object in the `map_button_action` method to do what you want.

```
//DestinationViewController.h

@interface DestinationViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) (SomeDataType*) propertyName;

@end 

//CurrentViewController.m

#import DestinationViewController

....

map_button_action{

    DestinationViewController *obj = [DestinationViewController new];
    obj.propertyName = someValue;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES]

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but would you mind giving me a code example of your proposal?

Comment: thank you, but using your proposal the SWRevealViewControllers structure is lost.

Comment: what is the structure?